# Need a way to get python object from marshmallow load function instead of dictionary without using post_load decorator

Tags: python, marshmallow

```
class ProfileSchema(Schema):

    id = fields.Integer()
    first_name = fields.String(required=True)
    last_name = fields.String()
    phone = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Email()
    gender = fields.String()
    city = fields.Str()
    state = fields.Str()
    country = fields.Str()
    age = fields.Int()
    id_proof = fields.Str()
    id_number = fields.Str()
    id_kyc_url = fields.Str()
    image_url = fields.Str()
    profile_type = fields.Str()
    country_code = fields.String()

    @validates('gender')
    def validate_gender(self, value):
        """
        validates gender
        :param value:
        :return:
        """
        if value not in genders:
            raise ValidationError('Incorrect gender value it should be either Male or Female')

    @post_load
    def make_profile(self, data):
        """
        make profile obj
        :param data:
        :return:
        """
        return Profile(**data)
```

In the above schema I am using post_load to convert the dict to an object. Is there anyway to get this without using the post_load decorator?

Comment: What's the usecase? Why don't you want to use post_load?

Comment: If I use a post_load I have to define another object with the same fields. This increases duplicity. If I add a new field tomorrow I have to check in multiple places to add that new field. Instead of that if the schema itself returns an object without explicitly specifying post_load, it would reduce this redundant definitions.

Comment: Also, postloads only run when there are no validation errors thrown.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, it's not the post_load decorator you have an issue with it's the redundancy of maintaining two object definitions. If that's the case, you can use [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.make_dataclass) to achieve what you want. You would still define a post_load method on your schema but would not longer have to maintain a second class definition.

**namedtuple solution**

```py
from collections import namedtuple

def make_object(class_name, members):
    obj = namedtuple(class_name, ' '.join(members.keys()))
    for k, v in members.items():
        setattr(obj, k, v)
    return obj
```

**dataclasses solution**

```py
from dataclasses import make_dataclass

def make_object(class_name, members):
    obj = make_dataclass(class_name, [(k, type(v)) for k,v in members.items()])
    for k, v in members.items():
        setattr(obj, k, v)
    return obj
```

```py
class ProfileSchema(Schema):

    id = fields.Integer()
    first_name = fields.String(required=True)
    last_name = fields.String()
    phone = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Email()
    gender = fields.String()
    city = fields.Str()
    state = fields.Str()
    country = fields.Str()
    age = fields.Int()
    id_proof = fields.Str()
    id_number = fields.Str()
    id_kyc_url = fields.Str()
    image_url = fields.Str()
    profile_type = fields.Str()
    country_code = fields.String()

    @validates('gender')
    def validate_gender(self, value):
        """
        validates gender
        :param value:
        :return:
        """
        if value not in genders:
            raise ValidationError('Incorrect gender value it should be either Male or Female')

    @post_load
    def make_profile(self, data):
        """
        make profile obj
        :param data:
        :return:
        """
        return make_object(data)
```

Comment: Or you create the object with a dataclass and generate the schema automatically with [marshmallow-dataclass](https://github.com/lovasoa/marshmallow_dataclass).